# Repair GRUB bootloader

Tags: grub, boot, boot-loader

I had [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu) installed on my laptop on hard disk drive */dev/sda* on partition */dev/sda1*.

Something bad happened and when I restarted my laptop, a black screen appeared with
"kernel panic" message.

So I decided to install [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) from a [live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD). I installed it on */dev/sda5* (it has a 6 GB size).

It was initially a swap partition, but I decided that I didn't need to have a swap partition, because I have 2 GB RAM.

So, I installed Lubuntu without problems.
After a restart, a black screen with the following message appeared:

> no such partition 
> grub rescue>

So I booted again from the live CD and changed the boot partition to */dev/sda5* in [fdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdisk). After a restart, I can only see the GRUB command line.

`fdisk -l` shows:

> Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696
> bytes
>  255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
> 19457 cylinders
>  Units = cylinders
> of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512
> bytes /512 bytes
>  I/O size
> (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512
> bytes
>  Disk identifier: 0x000c212c
>
> Device Boot      Start         End
> Blocks   Id  System
>  /dev/sda1     1       18706   150253568   83
> Linux
>  /dev/sda2           18706   19458  6034433    5  Extended
> /dev/sda5   *  18706       19458    6034432   83 Linux

How can I repair GRUB to be able to boot to */dev/sda5* with Lubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to see the GRUB menu coming up during boot, you can interrupt it with a key press.

Then select your Lubuntu entry, press <kbd>e</kbd> and check root, kernel showing all to *sda5*.

GRUB uses another naming scheme internally, so *sda5* would be *hd(0,4)*.

Then <kbd>b</kbd> to boot that entry.

If you only see the GRUB rescue screen, you can try the following to boot into your Lubuntu on *sda5*:

```
root hd(0,4)
kernel /path/to/vmlinux root=/dev/sda5
boot
```

Once booted, check with GRUB commands that you boot into Lubuntu each time.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can see after restart. It's not Grub menu and it's not rescue screen. It's grub command line now.
OK, I will try the commands you advise in grub command line. Could you tell me what is /path/to/vmlinux? thank you

Comment: It's the path to the kernel boot file. Should normaly be in /boot/.

Comment: *root hd(0,4)* was OK
*kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic root=/dev/sda5* writes *error: unknown command 'kernel'.*

Comment: I tried `linux` command instead of `kernel` command. I'm not sure which version of vmlinuz I chosen (there were more options).

After the `boot` command I was in my Lubuntu, but the touchpad and internet connection wasn't working.

I rebooted and I was again in grub command line instead of grub menu.

Comment: It worked now. I had to copy the `vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic` (I used bad version of kernel before) to the `/boot` directory in `/dev/sda1` and then I used the command  `linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic root=/dev/sda5`.
But after restart I always have to play with the grub command line.
I suppose that solution is in your sentence `Once booted check with Grub commands that you boot into Lubuntu each time.` Could you please explain how do you think it? thank you

Comment: grub-mkconfig should create a config file with the correct values once your system is loaded